# creating json from elixir ecto associations

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I would like to generate JSON from an ecto association in phoenix.

this is my association:

```
defmodule Blog.Post do
  use Ecto.Model

  schema "posts" do
    field :title, :string
    field :body, :string
    has_many :comments, Blog.Comment
  end
end
```

and:

```
defmodule Blog.Comment do
  use Ecto.Model

  schema "comments" do
    field :content, :string
    belongs_to :post, Blog.Post
  end
end
```

when I generate json without the association the result is this:

```
[%Blog.Post{body: "this is the very first post ever!", id: 1,title: "first post"},
 %Blog.Post{body: "Hello nimrod!!!!", id: 12, title: "hi Nimrod"},
 %Blog.Post{body: "editing the body!!!!", id: 6, title: "hello(edit)"}]
```

and the json looks like this

```
{"posts": [
    {
        "title": "first post",
        "id": 1,
        "body": "this is the very first post ever!"
    },
    {
        "title": "hi Nimrod",
        "id": 12,
        "body": "Hello nimrod!!!!"
    },
    {
        "title": "hello(edit)",
        "id": 6,
        "body": "editing the body!!!!"
    }
]}
```

but with the association the outcome is this

```
[%Blog.Post{body: "this is the very first post ever!",
 comments: {Ecto.Associations.HasMany.Proxy,
 #Ecto.Associations.HasMany<[name: :comments, target: Blog.Post,
 associated: Blog.Comment, references: :id, foreign_key: :post_id]>}, id: 1,
 title: "first post"},
 %Blog.Post{body: "Hello nimrod!!!!",
 comments: {Ecto.Associations.HasMany.Proxy,
 #Ecto.Associations.HasMany<[name: :comments, target: Blog.Post,
 associated: Blog.Comment, references: :id, foreign_key: :post_id]>}, id: 12,
 title: "hi Nimrod"},
 %Blog.Post{body: "editing the body!!!!",
 comments: {Ecto.Associations.HasMany.Proxy,
 #Ecto.Associations.HasMany<[name: :comments, target: Blog.Post,
 associated: Blog.Comment, references: :id, foreign_key: :post_id]>}, id: 6,
 title: "hello(edit)"}]
```

With the above output I can't create a proper json output. I would like for the json to look something like this

```
{"posts": [
     {
        "title": "the title",
        "id": 1,
        "body": "the body",
        "comments": [{"content": "a comment"}, {"content": "another comment"}]
     }
     ...
]}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which Library do you use to generate the JSON? Please add an example snippet.

Comment: It is the default phoenix library, Poison: 
`Poison.encode! %{posts: Blog.Repo.all(Blog.Post)}`

Comment: I am assuming you get an error, is that right? Can you please post the error here?

Comment: My error message looks like this: `** (Poison.EncodeError) unable to encode value: {Ecto.Associations.HasMany.Proxy, #Ecto.Associations.HasMany<[name: :comments, target: Blog.Post, associated: Blog.Comment, references: :id, foreign_key: :post_id]>}`

Answer (score 6):

Ouch, there is no easy solution at this moment. I would try something like:

```
defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Tuple do
  def encode(proxy, options) do
    Poison.Encoder.List.to_json(proxy.all, options)
  end
end
```

We are basically implementing encoder for tuples that receives the proxy above and encoding all items. We need to discuss better solutions for this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are doing... Could you maybe show an example of how you would do this.

Comment: This is a hack around Ecto's inability of rendering associations. You should add this to one of your project's file and it should be enough, unless I am missing something, but the proxy in the code above is the value returned by `post.comments`. The rational is that the association proxy is a tuple, so you are teaching Poison how to render those to JSON.

Comment: I tried adding this to my project and received the following warning: `warning: undefined protocol function encode/2 (for protocol Poison.Encoder)` and after I tried running `Poison.encode! Blog.Repo.all(Blog.Post)` I received this error: `** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Poison.Encoder.Tuple.encode/2
      (blog) Poison.Encoder.Tuple.encode({Ecto.Associations.HasMany.Proxy, #Ecto.Associations.HasMany<[name: :comments, target: Blog.Post, associated: Blog.Comment, references: :id, foreign_key: :post_id]>}, [])`

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the sample. It should use `encode` instead of `to_json`.